# Ideas for an algorithm to randomly place interrelated nodes

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, graph, logic

I apologise for the title, I realise it isn't especially descriptive. I'll try to describe my problem in greater detail.

I have a set of "nodes", for sake of example we'll title them A, B, C, D, and E. These nodes are unique from one another in the sense that they have are "related" to each other, though only to specific nodes. In my real implantation, there could be thousands of nodes and I would like to develop an algorithm which could place them appropriately, regardless of their quantity.

We'll pretend the associations are as follows:

```
A: B, D

B: A, C, D

C: E

D: A, B

E: C
```

This format means that A is related to B and D, etc.

My goal is to display these relationships on a 2D plane by drawing each node as a circle, and drawing a line between them. I would like to display them in a "web" type fashion, meaning that the nodes do not overlap whatsoever, and the distance between related nodes is minimized. I would like for the diagram to suggest that by starting at A, for instance, one could travel next to B, then to C, and finally to E.

In a case such as B's, where it itself is related to C while C is not related to B, there does not have to be a distinction to suggest that. That is to say, showing that A:B and B:A can be the same as saying that B:C, despite C is *not* related to B.

I hope I have made myself clear in what I would like to accomplish. I don't think I'll have very much trouble coding the actual algorithm, I just for the life of me can't think of a way logical way to approach the problem.

Any suggestions at all are greatly appreciated, I don't need pseudocode or step by step instructions, just some advice from some more seasoned programmers who may be able to look at the problem from a different perspective.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the edges (relationships of two nodes) also given to you? Or you want to 'make them up'?

Comment: It reminds me a bit of a graph drawing algorithm I implemented some years ago. The basic idea was to initialize the node positions randomly (putting them on a circle turned out to be good). Then apply forces between the nodes: they push each other apart. If they are related, there is an additional force, pulling them together. Repeat the force-step a few times which should give you a nice layout. I admit the algorithm was primary used for planar graphs, but I guess it could help you, too. try searching for "force directed graph drawing". found a live example at http://getspringy.com/

Comment: This seems like it could be very helpful! I'll take a look, hopefully something like this wouldn't be terribly difficult to implement in iOS.

@amit, yes, the edges are given to me.

Comment: I made it an answer in case it was really helpful :) I don't think it would be too difficult to implement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try searching for "force directed graph drawing".

The basic idea is as follows:

- Initialize node positions randomly (putting them with equal distances on a circle turned out to be good)
- Apply Forces between the nodes:

  - Nodes push off each other
  - if they are related, they are additionally pulled towards each other
- Repeat step 2 until you have a nice layout.

There is a live example at http://getspringy.com/

Comment: This pointed me in the direction I needed. 


I'm not sure if you have much experience with iOS or not, but do you think using SpriteKit would suffice?

My plan is to treat it like a physical system (a la first year university), and find the net force on each node using vector addition. The net force would be applied to each node using SpriteKits applyForce() method.


Would SpriteKit be able to do such a thing for hundreds, perhaps thousands of nodes (and forces)?

Comment: I don't have that much experience with SpriteKit's physics, I just did a simple test app with hundreds of colliding balls. That one's framerate dropped fast as there were more balls added. But I guess it's not about realtime animations in your case, so you could succeed with it. In order to "just calculate" the final positions, it would be better to do that yourself in a loop, since it would be faster than waiting for SpriteKit to redraw each frame and advance just a little step in time to do the same thing over again.